# Changing date to day before for certain daily time ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table with a datetime field and need to get it to work properly with other tables that have date fields that work on system date, not calendar date.

Our system day runs until 1:59 AM, so anything after midnight until then is considered the day before in all of these tables (which don't actually show datetime, just date).

I am trying to figure out how I can create a date field where '2019-01-01 01:45:00.111' would read as '2018-12-31', but '2019-01-01 2:00:00.111' would read as '2019-01-01'.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend having another field called something like "POSTED_DATE" to make it clear -- then having that store the modified date in addition to the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple logic below by removing 120 minutes from your each datetime value and then cast the datetime value as date.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,-120,<your_date_time_column>) AS DATE)
FROM <Your_Table>
```

Comment: I would subtract two hours, but this is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `CASE WHEN..` clause to increment or decrement dates by 1 like below sample

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DATE, 
   'HH:MM') BETWEEN '00:00' AND 
    '01:45' THEN DATE-1 ELSE 
     DATE END FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL Server syntax, so the upvotes are rather perplexing.